# Trapped Rooks: Does Stockfish penalize more if the king can't castle temporarily?

Tags: stockfish, programming, castling, evaluation, rooks

In [this talkchess thread](http://www.talkchess.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?p=575819&sid=604f7301762ea0d2f4cb746657e2a379#p575819), they discuss trapped rooks and castling rights. In post #5, user @Lyudmil Tsvetkov posted:

> I would give at least some 10-15cps for temporary prevention of castling.

Here is [how](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/995ee4b31105ad8c7976cc68c11fabfdc5108e63/src/evaluate.cpp#L366) StockFish implements it:

```
score -= TrappedRook * (1 + !pos.castling_rights(Us));
```

Here an example position.

```
r3kb1r/pp3ppp/4bn2/3p4/P7/4N1P1/1P2PPBP/R1B1K2R w Kq - 0 1
```

When searching, the move Bg2-f1 leads to the position.

```
r3kb1r/pp3ppp/4bn2/3p4/P7/4N1P1/1P2PP1P/R1B1KB1R b Kq - 1 1
```

As you can see, the White bishop has blocked castling, but `pos.castling_rights(Us)` for White still returns true, which means Stockfish is not penalizing for the temporary prevention of castling.

Is it intentional or is it a Stockfish bug?

Answer (score 1):

White hasn't lost his castling rights. It's just not a legal move right now. There is a distinction.

White would still be able to castle king-side, if the bishop were to move.